# Broken file upload with bootstrap

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap 4.0.0

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron mt-3" style="padding: 0.6em 1.6em;">
    <h4>Uploader</h4>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/myurl/?action=upload" method="POST">
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Upload">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

In combination with this PHP code on the other side:

```
<?php var_dump($_FILES); ?>
```

returns:

```
array(0) { }
```

In other words: I simply select a file, `/myurl/?action=upload` is called, but `empty($_FILES['myfile'])` is `TRUE` / no files seems to be passed.

What is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: The php really has nothing to do in this case. The file is not sent.

Comment: Then give your input a proper valid name attribute. name="uploaded_file" perhaps...

Comment: What about the php error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't provided a proper name attribute in your input field.

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="uploaded_file">
```

Would likely help this issue, but without seeing your PHP, it could be other issues.

Comment: It does not seems to be the problem. I've updated the code above with the name and also the PHP :)